# How accurate does the kernel density estimate need to be to use it in the mean shift algorithm?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, approximation, mean-shift

Mean shift is an iterative procedure for locating the maxima of a density function, given discrete data sampled from that function. It is useful for detecting the modes of this density.

How accurate does the kernel density estimate need to be for this algorithm to work?
For example, is it okay if it performs poorly in the tails and better at the mode?
I may want to use this for image segmentation.